# Square of a matrix problem

Tags: matrices

A real 2 × 2 matrix M such that 
$M^2=\begin{pmatrix}-1 &0 \\ 0 &-1-\epsilon \end{pmatrix}$

(A) exists for all $\epsilon$ > 0

(B) does not exist for any $\epsilon$ > 0

(C) exists for some $\epsilon$ > 0

(D) none of the above is true

Any hints as to how to approach this ? Which theory is required for this ?

Comment: It seems the size is small-enough so that you could try an equation for a generic matrix. Also, maybe you could specify the coefficients you're working with.

Comment: Note that if $M =[[a\, 0];[0\, b]]$ then $M^2 = [[a^2\, 0];[0 \,b^2]]$. Based on that I'm inclined towards (B). Alternatively, if $M =[[a\, b];[c\, d]]$ then we require the condition  $a = -d$ which is true for $\epsilon = -2$ which also points to (B).

Comment: I reached the conclusion that this is only true for $\epsilon = 0$, but can't see my error.  Maybe I should post it and see if others can spot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is over $\mathbb{C}$, then $M^2$ is Hermitian, and hence normal, and since $\mathbb{C}$ is closed under square roots ($\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra), then the result (A) follows.

If this is over $\mathbb{R}$, consider $M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\c & d\end{array}\right)$.  Suppose $\epsilon \geq 0$, and $M$ is of the form in the question.  Then:

$$M^2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a^2+bc & b(a+d)\\c(a+d) & bc+d^2\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} -1 & 0\\0 & -1-\epsilon\end{array}\right)$$

Then $a^2 + bc = -1$, $a(b+d) = 0$, $c(a+d) = 0$, $bc+d^2 = -1-\epsilon$.  We have a few cases to deal with:

- $a=0$:  In this case, we have: $cd = 0$, whence either $c = 0$ or $d = 0$  If $c = 0$, $a^2=-1$, which is impossible.  If $d = 0$, we have $bc = -1 = -1-\epsilon$, so $\epsilon = 0$.
- $a\neq 0$:  First, observe $c\neq 0$, $b\neq 0$, else $d^2 = -1-\epsilon$, which is impossible, and likewise, $a^2 = -1$, which is impossible.  So $b\neq 0$, $c\neq 0$, $a\neq 0$.  Then $a = -d$ (since $c\neq 0$), $b = -d$ (since $a\neq 0$).  Then $a=b$, $a^2 = d^2$, and $-1 = a^2+cb = d^2+cb = -1 - \epsilon$, whence $\epsilon = 0$.

I suppose we could also do the other cases (namely, $b = 0$, $b\neq 0$, $c=0$, $c\neq 0$, $d=0$, $d\neq 0$), but the above actually covers every possibility, and the conclusion is (B).

- $b=0$:  In this case, $a^2 = -1$, which is impossible.
- $b\neq0$:  In this case, $a+d=0$, whence $a = -d$.  Then $-1 = a^2+bc = d^2+bc = -1-\epsilon$, whence $\epsilon = 0$.
- $c=0$:  In this case, $a^2 = -1$, which is impossible.
- $c\neq0$:  In this case, $a+d=0$, whence $a = -d$.  Then $-1 = a^2+bc = d^2+bc = -1-\epsilon$, whence $\epsilon = 0$
- $d=0$:  In this case, $ab = 0$, whence $a=0$ or $b = 0$.  If $b = 0$, $a^2 =-1$, which is impossible.  If $a=0$, we have $-1 = bc = -1-\epsilon$, so $\epsilon = 0$.
- $d\neq 0$:  First, observe $b\neq 0$, $c\neq 0$.  Else, we have $a^2 = -1$, $d^2=-1-\epsilon$, both of which are impossible.  So $b\neq 0$, $c\neq 0$.  Then since $d\neq 0$, $c\neq 0$, $b\neq 0$, we have $a+d = 0$, whence $a = -d$, and hence $-1 = a^2 - bc = d^2-bc = -1-\epsilon$, whence $\epsilon = 0$.

So if looking for a real square root, we can only have $\epsilon\leq 0$, leading to (B), barring arithmetic/logical errors.

---

Disclaimer:

I feel like there may very well be an error in the arithmetic above, but I can't spot it.  Please let me know if there is a mistake here, or if anything is unclear, and I'll elaborate or correct this as needed.

---

Answer (score 0):

*Hints.* Here are two different approaches to your question.

1. If $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $M$, then (up to reordering of indices) $\lambda_1^2=-1$ and $\lambda_2^2=-1-\epsilon$ are the eigenvalues of $M^2$. Note that nonreal eigenvalues of a real matrix must occur in pairs of conjugates.
2. When $\epsilon>0$, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem,
   $$\operatorname{tr}(M)M=M^2+\det(M)I=\operatorname{diag}(-1,-1-\epsilon)\pm\sqrt{1+\epsilon}\ I\ne0.$$
   It follows that $\operatorname{tr}(M)\ne0$ and $M$ must be a real diagonal matrix.